# How to make association between shares?

Tags: java, oop

[image]

I'm new to Java and i have to do this diagram, but i have a lot of problems, in Company i have the following:

```
  public class Company {
    private String name;

    public Company (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In Share:

```
 public class Share  {
    private double value;
    private Company company;

    public Share(double value, Company company) {
        this.value = value;
        this.company = company;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

And in Portofolio i have:

```
    public class Portofolio {
   private int noShares;
   Share[] shares = new Share[5];
   private int numberOfShares = 0;

    public Portofolio(int noShares) {
        this.noShares = noShares;
    }

    public void addShare(Share newShare) {
    if (shares == null) {
        shares = new Share[0];
    }
    else {
        Share[] newShares = new Share[numberOfShares+1];
        System.arraycopy(shares, 0, newShares, 0, numberOfShares);
        shares = newShares;
    }

    shares[numberOfShares++] = newShare;
    newShare.setValue(this);
    }
public double computeSum() {
        double sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < shares.length; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public int getNoShares() {
        return noShares;
    }

    public Share[] getShares() {
        return shares;
    }
}
```

So how it is said in the image i need to compute the values that i added, the problem is when i try to use this keyword, the required type is double, but the provided is Portofolio. So my question is what i need to do in order to be able to sum the shares correctly like in the image?

Comment: "to use this keyword it is expecting double" ... simply isnt a clear problem description. Please read [mcve] and enhance your code accordingly. Provide the compiler error message for example.

Comment: Yes, i know i can edit, but my question is different so i tough it's better to make another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following line from `addShare`, it does not make sense:

```
newShare.setValue(this);
```

You should also remove the redundant definition of `numberOfShares` and consistently use `noShares` instead (in fact, neither of them are necessary because Java arrays know their own lengths — but your exercise requires it, so stick with it).

Next, remove the constructor, it also doesn’t make sense.

Furthermore, your `computeSum` method sums the indices, not the share values. Change it to

```
public double computeSum() {
    double sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < noShares; i++) {
        sum += shares[i].getValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The final version of the `Portfolio` class should look something like this:

```
public class Portofolio {
    private int noShares;
    private Share[] shares;

    public void addShare(Share newShare) {
        if (shares == null) {
            shares = new Share[0];
        } else {
            Share[] newShares = new Share[noShares + 1];
            System.arraycopy(shares, 0, newShares, 0, noShares);
            shares = newShares;
        }

        shares[noShares++] = newShare;
    }

    public double computeSum() {
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < shares.length; i++) {
            sum += shares[i].getValue();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: God, thanks a lot, i forgot to get each value, that s why wasnt working.